# My old dog hasn't eaten anything for a week

Tags: dogs, health, feeding, veterinarian

My dog is an old Schnauzer, 15 years old to be specific. A week ago we went to the vet because of a relatively simple respiratory problem he had, and the vet injected anti-inflammatory and analgesic drugs, and since then my dog hasn't eaten absolutely anything and everything we try results in him having diarrhea or vomiting.

We asked the vet and he said we can try with electrolyte water and soft food, like baby food or boiled chicken with rice, until we have encouraged him to eat. So we went to a second vet, for other opinion, and she said that the dog still has respiratory problems - she prescribed Amoxin and soft diet, but nothing improved in terms of dog's appetite.

I'm desperate, what can I do to help my dog? I need to give him the nutrients he needs. He had been eating relatively well for his age until that day. I'm not sure what happened. Aside, he has been walking a lot in the recent days.

Thank you and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Did he eat the chicken and rice? That is the normal treatment (bland diet) for stomach upset. Your veterinarian might have a prescription dog food that could help temporarily too until his system returns to normal.

Comment: You said that your dog walks a lot recently. I wonder if he's walking so much because he's uncomfortable sitting or lying down. That might indicate that something else is wrong in addition to the respiratory problem. Have you mentioned this to your vet?

Comment: Thanks for all your comments but unfortunately my dog passed away the Tuesday by liver problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try giving your dog some rice milk to settle his stomach. Another thing you can try is putting a tablespoon of olive oil in his food. If your dog has no appetite and begins getting weaker, definitely take him back to the vet.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments but unfortunately my dog passed away this Tuesday by liver fail, the vet considered the best option because the condition of his liver.

Comment: I'm so sorry for your loss :(